# I have a dynamic html template. Which forms when I click on a button. Now, the problem is When I click on one button all buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript

Here is the html template forms when I click on a button.

```
<div class="detail">
                    <h3>${element.name}</h3>
                    <p>Phone: ${element.phone}</p>
                    <button onclick="addToHistory()">Call</button>
                </div>`
```

Let's say it creates two template as it is.

```
<div class="detail">
                        <h3>Person1</h3>
                        <p>Phone: 0111111111</p>
                        <button onclick="addToHistory()">Call</button>
                    </div>`

<div class="detail">
                        <h3>Person2</h3>
                        <p>Phone: 0111111111</p>
                        <button onclick="addToHistory()">Call</button>
                    </div>`
```

Now, I want to click on one button and then according to my click I want the data of clicked divs should store.

I tried this using event handler as you can see with addToHistory() function. But, it stores all the data both I clicked and not clicked also.

Please note: I want to do this only using JavaScript. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `this` into your method and use that to traverse within the specific `detail` container where the button was clicked.

`this` will reference the specific element the event occurs on

```js
function addToHistory(el){
   console.log(el.previousElementSibling.textContent);
}
```

```html
<div class="detail">
  <h3>Person1</h3>
  <p>Phone: 0999999999</p>
  <button onclick="addToHistory(this)">Call</button>
</div>`

<div class="detail">
  <h3>Person2</h3>
  <p>Phone: 0111111111</p>
  <button onclick="addToHistory(this)">Call</button>
</div>`
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working. But, it gives me only phone number. Can you please help me with getting the person name also?

Comment: Ok well perhaps you should do some research on how to traverse. You can use closest() to go to the detail and query inside for the heading element. Please understand this isn;t a free code writing service

Comment: Yes, I did research according to your suggestion. I got my solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, of course.